# using a framework for two different view controllers and array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

I m using `cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards`. It's working fine on my `First view controller`. Now I want to use this in different View controller with different `JSON` array. How can I achieve this? This is how I do in my `first ViewController` :

```
   CGRect frame = self.invitationViewContainer.frame;
    //frame.origin.y = -self.view.frame.size.height; //optional: if you want the view to drop down
       DraggableViewBackground *draggableBackground =     [[DraggableViewBackground alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    draggableBackground.alpha = 0; //optional: if you want the view to fade in

    [draggableBackground loadCards:_arrAllCards];

    [self.invitationViewContainer addSubview:draggableBackground];
```

and in `DraggableViewBackground ViewClass` :

```
   -(void)loadCards:(NSArray*)array
   {

    exampleCardLabels = array;


     if([exampleCardLabels count] > 0) {
    NSInteger numLoadedCardsCap =(([exampleCardLabels count] >  MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)?MAX_BUFFER_SIZE:[exampleCardLabels count]);
     //%%% if the buffer size is greater than the data size, there will be an array error, so this makes sure that doesn't happen



       //%%% loops through the exampleCardsLabels array to create a card for each label.  This should be customized by removing "exampleCardLabels" with your own array of data
       for (int i = 0; i<[exampleCardLabels count]; i++) {
        DraggableView* newCard = [self createDraggableViewWithDataAtIndex:i];
        [allCards addObject:newCard];

        if (i<numLoadedCardsCap) {
            //%%% adds a small number of cards to be loaded
            [loadedCards addObject:newCard];
        }
    }
```

for different JSON array can I use the same Classes or I have to make different classes?

Comment: Not getting your question properly!

Comment: Yes, you can use this class with different JSON array.

Comment: how can it be used then ...@SaurabhJain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use same DraggableViewBackground class for multiple viewcontrollers. You just need to change the array from this line,

```
[draggableBackground loadCards: yourArray];
```

If you want to change the design & data of card, you can use another DraggableViewBackground class. Copy all methods from DraggableViewBackground to your new DraggableViewBackground class.

In the new DraggableViewBackground.m change `-(void)setupView` method according your design. 
Change `-(DraggableView *)createDraggableViewWithDataAtIndex:(NSInteger)index` method according to your data.

And use new DraggableViewBackground class to your secondViewController.

Comment: ok but data appears on the card also need to change according to model ....what can we do with it 
    MGInvitationModel *model = [self.exampleCardLabels objectAtIndex:index];
    
       namelabel.text = model.senderName;

Comment: Not getting your question properly. Do you want to change the design of the card?